# Is there any recycling pool structure in C++ Boost?

Tags: c++, performance, boost

I need a pool struct that can reuse/recycle the memory after usage, i.e., DON'T do any allocation or deallocation on-the-fly (although you still need to allocate the memory at the moment when the program starts)

Boost.Pool does not support such a mechanism; is there any alternative?

Answer (score 2):

What about just allocating a lot of space for the pool as soon as you create it? The function [`pool::orderedMalloc(n)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/pool/doc/interfaces/pool.html) seems to do just that.

Yes, you're still allocating at "runtime", but only as the process starts.

Answer (score 1):

The standard heap mechanisms reuse memory after it is released; a single address range may be used by many different values over the lifetime of a program.  However, as you suggest, such mechanisms do acquire memory from the system as needed at runtime.

If you need to preallocate a suitable size chunk of memory and then dole out allocations from that, you'd be looking at sensitive stuff like overloading global operator `new` and its friends to do allocation out of the preallocated space, presumably throwing exceptions when the preallocated space runs out.  [Don't try this without adult supervision - and don't look to me for that supervision; I'm a chicken!]